# How css cascading works here?

Tags: html, css, less

Consider a html element

```
<input type="text" class="name-input" />
```

Style sheet has following css

```
.name-input {
  //some styles here
}


[type="text"] {
  //other styles here
}
```

But in output it displaying both styles for the element. I tried by giving `#id` to input element as well still it's cascading both. Can someone explain me a way to get only `.name-input` styles to element. Thanks in advance

Comment: please add a comment before down voting. So that i can correct it?

Answer (score 0):

Selectors has Priority.

> Resource:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

`id selector` has High priority than `class Selector` and `attribute Selector`.
priority `class Selector` is same `attribute Selector` and Each one come next other get High priority.

use of `.name-input {` after of `[type="text"]{` like this:

```
[type="text"] {
  //other styles here
}

.name-input {
  //some styles here
}
```

when do it, `.name-input{` rules overlay `[type="text"]{` rules.

```css
[type="text"] {
  background-color: blue;
}

.name-input {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="" class="name-input">
```

> If you use of `Id Selector`,place rule not important,Because `id` has High priority.

```css
#myId {
  background-color: green;
}

[type="text"] {
  background-color: blue;
}

.name-input {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="myId" type="text" name="" class="name-input">
```

Answer (score 0):

If this style is required for all other text boxes and only this text box is exception, use id as follows

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<Style>
.name-input {
  background-color: #45a049;
}
input[type="text"] {
   width: 100%;
}
#id1{
width: 50%;
}
</Style>
<body >
<input id="id1" type="text" class="name-input" />
</body>
</html>
```

in id1 selector give whatever you require to over write the type selector.